# Add a New Record to Microsoft Access Database using VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010

I have a form called (Registration), and a database called (UsersLogin) with a table called (tbl_user) with the fields

- (first_name)
- (last_name)
- (middle_name)
- (age)
- (address)
- (username)
- (password).

I want to not only be able to edit records (I can already do this), but I cant seem to be able to add/create a new row/record. Below is the class `registration` I am using so far to **update** a database row, but I can't seem to be able to 'add' a new record (rather than simply updating):

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Registration
    Private Sub Registration_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            Me.Tbl_userTableAdapter.Fill(Me.UsersLoginDataSet.tbl_user)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("The database file is unavailable", "Database Unavailable", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
            Me.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSaveChanges_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSaveChanges.Click
        Try
            Me.Validate()
            Me.TbluserBindingSource.EndEdit()
            Me.Tbl_userTableAdapter.Update(Me.UsersLoginDataSet)
            MessageBox.Show("Updates to the database have been successful.", "Successful Updates", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Updates to the database have failed.", "Unsuccessful Updates", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        LoginScreen.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub
End Class
```

The dataset is called `UsersLoginDataSet.xsd`

Anyone know how to add a new user (i.e. make a new row), and hence write this to a table?

I have looked for several solutions to this on the web, but have not been able to add a new row and hence "fill" the record in the database.

Could anyone possibly explain how this *should* be done?

Comment: It is not very useful to say "but I cant seem to be able to create a new row". You need to provide details so we can help you. Why can't you? Are you getting an error, what error? Also you need to provide the SQL of the `Command`s of your`SqlDataAdapter`. And one last note: You have both MySQL and MS Access tags on your question, which database are you using?

Comment: @RacilHilan Sorry about that. I'm using MS access. But I've tried using dim row As New Datarow, But nothing actually happened.

Comment: You need to provide more details as I mentioned. `Dim row As New Datarow` does not mean much. Are you then adding it to the table? I will try to post an answer, but the details you've provided are not enough.

Comment: Sorry, not very good at asking questions tbh, but yes, What I want to be able to do is add a new user to the system, and this will then be able to be used in the login of the system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The details you provided are not enough, but I will try to answer according to your comment. Below is a example from MSDN about how to add a new row. When you create the new row, you have to use `NewRow()` on the table, and after creating it use `Rows.Add()` on your table to add the new row:

```
Dim newCustomersRow As DataRow = DataSet1.Tables("Customers").NewRow()

newCustomersRow("CustomerID") = "ALFKI"
newCustomersRow("CompanyName") = "Alfreds Futterkiste"

DataSet1.Tables("Customers").Rows.Add(newCustomersRow)
```

Form more details, you read the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ycd1034.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).